# How to see my Lightning component in salesforce?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, developer-console

I'm building some lightning component in the developer console, so I have some aura:component.
But I would like to see those component, I have create them but I'm not able to see them because I don't know where I should go to do that in salesforce ...

I'm not sure if my question is clear, so thank you for your help and I can try explain myself better if you need.

Comment: Try https://github.com/sonicfurqan/LWC-Viewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

goto - developer console

[image]

Create a lightning App and add you component here and click on right side preview button This will open application and you can see your component..

You need to add

```
<c:yourcomponentName  />
```

If there are few attribute you have created in component then you need pass value

```
<c:yourcomponentName  attributeName="value" anotherAttribute="Value" />
```

[image]

You can also use Lightning App builder..

Note: You need to add implement in your component.

```
implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
                                        forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"
```

Comment: Thank you @Ratan I just tested it and it's working for some ligthning component. But sometimes I get some error, like "Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application." And it tell me there is an error with the connection but so why does some of my app are working ? Anyway I thank you for the detailled answer :)

Comment: @dou I am not sure, may be for few your components having fault code that may be causing error, just guessing.